# How to define PUT method for complex json objects for updating records in mongoDB using nodejs scripts?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I want to define a put method by using `findOneAndUpdate()` on a mongoDB object using AngularJS. I am able to successfully do `GET` and `POST` operations but I am having difficulty defining `PUT`. Below is my db object defined in `app.js` file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testing23');

    var idObj = Schema({

        _id: String,
        name : {
            firstname : String,
            lastname : String
        },
        phones : [Number],
        emails : [String],
        friends : [String]

    });
var Error = mongoose.model('Error', idObj );
```

My `GET` and `POST` are below:

```
app.get('/api/info',function(req,res){
    Error.find(function(err,infos){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
        return res.json(infos);
    });
});
app.post('/api/info',function(req,res){
    Error.create(req.body, function(err,infos){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
        return res.json(infos);
    });
});
```

For `PUT` I am using below method but it is not working:

```
app.put('/api/infos/:id',function(req,res){

    Error.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},req.body,function(err,infos){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
        return res.json(infos);
    });
});
```

How can I successfully do a `PUT` operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) your find and modify command should look like the following

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { name: 'jason bourne' }}, options, callback)
```

For the example you provided and say you want to update the name, it would be

```
Error.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},{ $set: { name: req.body }},{new: true},function(err,updatedInfos){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
        return res.json(updatedInfos);
    });
```

Using `{new:true}` means the updated document gets returned.